# Unity C# How to get country, city or location of a player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geolocation

I've a game where I'm trying to keep my own analytics. No pin point location, is there something similar to `SystemInfo` class that could give approximate location of the player?

I know I can tap into the GPS but I don't want to make things complicated. Just a simple city or country will do.

Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too, so I wanted to make as simple of a solution as possible. Unfortunately, it wasn't easy:

```
[Serializable]
public class IpApiData
{
    public string country_name;

    public static IpApiData CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<IpApiData>(jsonString);
    }
}


public static IEnumerator SetCountry()
{
    string ip = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");
    string uri = $"https://ipapi.co/{ip}/json/";


    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
        int page = pages.Length - 1;

        IpApiData ipApiData = IpApiData.CreateFromJSON(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);

        Debug.Log(ipApiData.country_name);
    }
}
```

This will get the country, no problem. If you want to change it to city, or anything else, you'll just have to add some fields to `IpApiData`, as per this link: https://ipapi.co/api/#complete-location

Comment: If you're making the request from the player's device you won't get rate limited

Answer (score 1):

You can either ask the user for their details or send a request to your web server where that uses something like [ipdata.co](https://ipdata.co/) to track where the IP address came from.

Answer (score 0):

You can first take the IP of the player. I think this might help [answers.unity.com/questions/518346/get-ipv4-adress](https://answers.unity.com/questions/518346/get-ipv4-adress.html).
Then use any site IP-tracker to find the location. (like [ipstack](https://ipstack.com))